# How can I remove bedrock in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know if it is possible to remove bedrock in Minecraft. I watched videos on it and they failed. Is it actually possible?

Comment: What version are you playing in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note: This no longer works as of [1.8.2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.8.2)**

It's actually possible to break bedrock using dark oak trees. This is only advisable for the nether ceiling as it doesn't involve falling into the void. Once you're on the ceiling (using ender pearls thrown up from as high as you can get in the nether) grow a dark oak tree. Mine out the first level of trunk and plant four more saplings and bonemeal them. If you're lucky, the tree will grow downward and take out some bedrock. You might have to play around with it a bit to get a hole that works for you, but if you stick with it, you can get what you want.

This trick should work fine for bedrock in other places too, but it's pretty hard to be very precise, and it really only works for bedrock below the level of the saplings.

Comment: Is this a bug, or is it an intended feature?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug, but it's been in the game since Dark Oak trees were added, including 1.8 snapshots, so it doesn't seem like it's getting taken out anytime soon. Use it while you can! :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this bug was removed/fixed sometime in between 1.7.2/1.7.3-4. Like I said, not sure.

Comment: Well, Etho has used the glitch within the past couple weeks on the Mindcrack server and in his single player world, and both worlds are using the latest snapshots. I've also personally used the glitch a month or two ago in 1.7.8 or 9.

Comment: It should be noted that this "bug" has been fixed (1.8.2 pre4) and it is not possible to break bedrock with trees. Hopefully someone will find a new way.

Answer (score 3):

In 1.7.9 you can also place a slab under the bedrock and place a wither skeleton skull on the slab in the half-block space, and the bedrock will be replaced.

Comment: That's a good tip, I didn't know that, and it works pretty well. Much more controllable than the dark oak trick. You get the skull back, too, which is good.

Comment: This bug was fixed in 1.8

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to remove bedrock in survival, that's why everyone else has failed. The only way to remove it is in creative, Though I don't see why you would want to. Beneath bedrock is the void.

Comment: This is only true pre 1.7, after 1.7 you can use the method mentioned above.